# Packet Sniffing on wlan0 is saying 0 packets captured

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, kali-linux, tcpdump

I am trying to practice some packet sniffing on my virtual machine using tcpdump and writing it to a pcap file. I put wlan0 into monitor mode using these commands:

ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode Monitor
ifconfig wlan0 up

I then used the command 
tcpdump -i wlan0 -s 1500 -v -w traffic.pcap
to capture packets. However, it is saying that wlan0 has captured 0 packets. I am pretty sure this is cause all traffic is going through the eth0 interface, but I am not sure how to have the traffic go through the wlan0 interface as wlan0 can support monitor mode. Any help would be great thanks! Also I am running this on kali linux.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. If you want to sniff your own traffic you could sniff the eth0 interface and it's not a requirement to have the network interface in monitor mode.

Comment: Maybe you really haven't setup monitor mode and/or you're on a channel that has no activity? Did you study https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN

Comment: I am trying to sniff all traffic on a wireless network. @Anonymous

Comment: I have tried changing between channels 1,6, and 11 but still have got nothing, which shouldn't be the case especially since my wireless network is on channel 11, and I am pretty sure I have set up monitor mode because when I do iwconfig it states that my mode is in monitor. I'm not sure if the problem is because the networks around me are secure. @sawdust